# How to use SensorManager.getOrientation() instead of TYPE_ORIENTATION

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

I am doing an app in android. The app have some quotes saved in database and I want to slide the quotes in the screen using the sensors of the phone. So I want that when the phone moves to the left I can see in the screen the next quote and when I move the phone to the right to see in the screen the previous quote.  What type of sensor phone  do you think is better to use?  I am trying to use Type_orientation but I have the error that :This constant was deprecated in API level 8. How can I replace it with SensorManager.getOrientation() .
Or do you think is there any other sensor that is better for me to use?

```
package com.example.prova1;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class SlideQuote extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
 //a TextView
 private TextView quote;
 private TextView author;
 //the Sensor Manager
 private SensorManager sManager;
 float x;
 int id;
 int total;
 String s1,s2;
  Database quotedatabase = new Database(this);


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_quote);

        //get the TextView from the layout file
        quote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
id=1;
        //get a hook to the sensor service

        sManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     if(sManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION).size()!=0){
      Sensor s =sManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION).get(o);
      sManager.registerListener(this,s ,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      s1= quotedatabase.getQuote(id);
      s2= quotedatabase.getAuthor(id);
      total=quotedatabase.getQuotesCount();


      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);
    }
    }
    //when this Activity starts
    @Override
 protected void onResume()
 {
  super.onResume();
  /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the
  callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as quick
  as possible*/
  sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

  //When this Activity isn't visible anymore
 @Override
 protected void onStop()
 {
  //unregister the sensor listener
  sManager.unregisterListener(this);
  super.onStop();
 }

 @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1)
 {
  //Do nothing.
 }

 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
  //if sensor is unreliable, return void
  if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
  {
   return;
  }
  //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
  x=event.values[2];

  if(x>25){
   if(id==total)
   {id=1;
   }
   else{

   id++;
   }
   s1= quotedatabase.getQuote(id);
      s2= quotedatabase.getAuthor(id);
      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);

  }
  if(x<-25){
   if(id==1)
   {id=total;}
   else{
   id--;}

   s1= quotedatabase.getQuote(id);
      s2= quotedatabase.getAuthor(id);      
      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);
  }
  }
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  sManager.unregisterListener(this);
  Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), Quote.class);
       finish();
       startActivity(backIntent);

 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android Motion Sensor page is giving some examples to use the sensors:

[Android Motion Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)

For the gyro you can use the following code:

```
// Create a constant to convert nanoseconds to seconds.
private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
private final float[] deltaRotationVector = new float[4]();
private float timestamp;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  // This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
  // after computing it from the gyro sample data.
  if (timestamp != 0) {
    final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
    // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
    float axisX = event.values[0];
    float axisY = event.values[1];
    float axisZ = event.values[2];

    // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
    float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

    // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
    // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
    if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
      axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
    }

    // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
    // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
    // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
    // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
    float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
    float sinThetaOverTwo = sin(thetaOverTwo);
    float cosThetaOverTwo = cos(thetaOverTwo);
    deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
    deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
    deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;
    deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
  }
  timestamp = event.timestamp;
  float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
    // User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
    // in order to get the updated rotation.
    // rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
   }
}
```

Comment: How does that replace **TYPE_ORIENTATION** listener?